# Offensive rebounding % on missed 3FG vs 2FG (NBA)

Tags: statistics, nba

- Amongst missed 3FG, what % are rebounded by the offensive team?
- Amongst missed 2FG, what % are rebounded by the offensive team?

Is there a significant difference between these two percentages?

Answer (score 3):

[image: from Grantland.com]

The great Kirk Goldsberry included this graphic in his (in)famous article on the "Kobe Assist."[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3KH3.jpg) It looks like 2-point field goals are more likely to be rebounded by the offensive team than are 3-point field goals, but this depends on team and precise location.

Comment: That is a good answer.  Of course if you shoot 2 feet from basket there is a really good chance you would get your miss.  Also most blocked shots happen closer to the basket.  If you get your own shot that was blocked you get an offensive board.

Comment: Can you link to the original article/source?